# Visual Basic Drop Down Field Required

Tags: vba, drop-down-menu, ms-word, required

Is there a code to make a drop down list a required field when making a form in word. I have the code to make a free text field required but not a drop down. Below is what i have for free text

```
Sub MustFillIn()
    If ActiveDocument.FormFields("CompName").Result = "" Then
        Do
            sInFld = InputBox("This field is required, please fill in below.")
        Loop While sInFld = ""
        ActiveDocument.FormFields("CompName").Result = sInFld
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution for any formfield is to test whether it is displaying the default text or is empty. For example, you could have each of the 'compulsory' formfields given the 'GetBkMk' below as an on_entry macro and the 'MustComplete' macro as an on_exit macro. Only the one pair of such macros is required for all text & dropdown formfields in a document.

```
Option Explicit
Dim BkMk As String, bSel As Boolean

Sub AutoOpen()
With ActiveDocument.FormFields(1)
  If .EntryMacro = "GetBkMk" Then BkMk = .Name
End With
End Sub

Sub GetBkMk()
  If bSel = False Then
    BkMk = Selection.Bookmarks(1).Name
    bSel = True
  Else
    With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(BkMk).Range.Fields(1)
      If .Type = wdFieldFormTextInput Then .Result.Select
      If .Type = wdFieldFormDropDown Then .Select
    End With
  End If
End Sub

Sub MustComplete()
With ActiveDocument.FormFields(BkMk)
  Select Case .Type
    Case wdFieldFormTextInput
      If .Result = .TextInput.Default Or .Result = "" Then
        bSel = True
        Application.OnTime When:=Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), Name:="GetBkMk"
        MsgBox "This field is required, please complete it."
      Else
        bSel = False
      End If
    Case wdFieldFormDropDown
      If .Result = .DropDown.ListEntries(1).Name Then
        bSel = True
        Application.OnTime When:=Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), Name:="GetBkMk"
        MsgBox "This field is required, please make a selection."
      Else
        bSel = False
      End If
  End Select
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and used the same code as you. This code can still work for a drop-down; Unfortunately, with this code, you will force the user to type out their answer instead of requiring the user to choose from the pre-designed list.

In order to use this specific code with the drop-down, the result needs to equal what we want to trigger this message. i.e. "Choose an item". So, now the first choice in your list should say "Choose an item", so when the user tabs over, it will prompt that message and force a response from the user. I'm hoping to find a better solution than this, but here is what it would look like.

```
Sub MustFillIn()
    If ActiveDocument.FormFields("CompName").Result = "Choose an item" Then
        Do
            sInFld = InputBox("This field is required, please fill in below.")
        Loop While sInFld = "Choose an item"
        ActiveDocument.FormFields("CompName").Result = sInFld
    End If
End Sub
```